# How do I disable jQuery Datepicker days after init?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Please take a look at this code:

```js
var array = ["2013-03-14","2013-03-15","2013-03-16"]

$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

This disables dates during initialization. How can I disable additional days after the initialization?

Answer (score 0):

Your code already does this. The `array` variable containing the dates to disable is read every time the datepicker is shown. Because of this you can simply update its values and it will automatically reflect those changes the next time it is loaded.

```js
var array = ["2015-05-14","2015-05-15","2015-05-16"]

$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});

$('button').click(function() {
    array.push('2015-05-20', '2015-05-21', '2015-05-22');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<input />

<button>Disable more days</button>
```

To view this in action, first click the `input` to see the initial disabled days. Then click the `button` and open the datepicker again to see the extra disabled dates.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because in the real-world case there is a function assigned to "beforeShowDay" that I can't modify and it doesn't just check them in an array. So I need a way to externally disable more dates.